# Are Exchange IPM.Contact properties 0x8043 and 0x8044 documented?

Tags: exchange-server, contacts, samsung-mobile, custom-fields, msg

In MSG file of **IPM.Contact** (Contact > Save As... > MSG), I can see entries with IDs **8043** and **8044** inserted by Samsung Contacts app to store sample values `IMAddress2` and `IMAddress3` which I manually entered into contact record in Samsung phone: (and waited for sync with outlook.com using standard Exchange connector)

> __substg1.0_**8043**001F → `IMAddress2`
>   __substg1.0_**8044**001F → `IMAddress3`

I cannot see these field IDs explicitly listed in the [MS-OXPROPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148) document. Are they from some range intended for custom use? Or do they have their regular column names somewhere? Can be they visualized in the Outlook UI by adding custom columns with proper names into list view?

(See also: [Initial question from user viewpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/1513624/outlook-contacts-view-custom-contact-fields-created-by-mobile-phone) which led to writing of this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are as you suggest what might be called "custom properties."

MS-OXPROPS [Section 1.3.3: Property ID Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/ed38d6e3-2871-4cb5-ab3e-0aebe9d02c21) says:

> Range Minimum: 0x8000
>
> Range Maximum: 0xFFFF
>
> Description: Reserved for mapping to named properties. The exceptions to this rule are some of the address book tagged properties (those with names beginning with  PIDTagAddressBook). Many are static property IDs but are in this range.

Named Properties are defined in [MS-PST, Section 2.4.2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-pst/60003704-dfa6-476f-b782-ce8bb52a2df3):

> Named properties are a special type of properties which reside in a reserved range of property identifier values (that is, WORD values between 0x8000 and 0x8FFF). Named properties, unlike standard properties, have names and meanings that are context-specific.

These properties are exported to msg files, in the [Named Property Mapping Storage (MS-OXMSG Section 2.2.3 & ff)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/193c169b-0628-4392-aa51-83009be7d71f).